# Как переделать код под динамическую память?

Tags: windows, c, c++

Форматированный кусок кода:
    char strToAdd[100000]="";
    char Temp[100]="";

```
sprintf_s(Temp,"%d",myBaseData.GetLength(i-1));
temp = atoi(Temp);
for(int j=0; j<temp; j++){
    sprintf_s(Temp, "%.2f", myBaseData.GetSeq(1, j+int(myBaseData.GetLabel(i-1))));
    strcat_s(strToAdd, Temp);
    sprintf_s(Temp, "%.2f", myBaseData.GetSeq(0, j+int(myBaseData.GetLabel(i-1))));
    if (atof(Temp)>=0)
        strcat_s(strToAdd, "+");
    strcat_s(strToAdd, Temp);
    strcat_s(strToAdd, "i; ");
}
item.pszText=(LPSTR)(strToAdd);
```

Как этот кусок кода можно переделать под динамическую память?

Comment: Берете и переделываете. Ф-циям работы со строками без разницы где находится сама строка - на стеке или в куче. Указателю ведь все равно куда указывать.

Comment: Ах, да. И коли используете C++, то используйте std::string. Жизнь сразу станет существенно проще. Ну, или аналоги TString или CString, если таковые предоставляются средой программирования.

Comment: Просто возник вопрос, как дописать в динамическую переменную в цикле? Если просто без цикла, то понятно сохраняем старый указатель в новый и увеличиваем его. Но как быть в цикле? Точно так же? Я ничего не потеряю?

Comment: <i>как дописать в динамическую переменную в цикле?</i><p>
Просто дописываете, как если бы она была на стеке. Главное - не вылезти за диапазон.

Comment: Интересно, чем стек забит? 100000 байт это не тот размер. В простом тесте на XP переполнение наступило после char str[2\*1024\*1024-16000]. Распечатайте temp перед циклом. Проверяйте, достаточно ли места в strToAdd перед strcat_s().

Answer (score 2):

На C вместо

```
char strToAdd[100000] = "";
char Temp[100] = "";
```

имеем

```
char *strToAdd = (char *)malloc(100000);
char *Temp[] = (char *)malloc(100);
```

Перед использованием проверка:

```
if (strToAdd != NULL && Temp != NULL) {
}
```

После использования освобождение:

```
free(strToAdd);
free(Temp);
```

А остальное без изменений.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, а если  вместо чистых Сей у Вас C++, будет похоже, но немного по-другому:

```
char* strToAdd = new char[100000];
char* Temp = new char[100];' // хотя лучше всё-таки оставить буфер в стеке.
```

проверка перед использованием не нужна: new никогда не возвращает NULL, при ошибке выкинет exception, который не заметить сложно.

после использования освобождение:

```
delete [] strToAdd;
delete [] Temp;
```

А вообще для строк лучше либо использовать готовый класс (`std::string` из STL, `CString` из MFC, к примеру), либо взять хороший чужой код, и только в крайнем случае писать свой, но только один раз и на все случаи жизни и аккуратно.

Comment: Одни из нас программируют хорошо, другие плохо, но ничего тут не изменишь (... цитата из классики ...). В общем, писать надо чаще и именно свой код, потом терять (случайно тереть) его и писать еще и еще раз. Я не шучу, напишите одно и то же несколько раз с интервалом в год и Вы увидите как все улучшилось.

Comment: Простите, не понял Ваc. Какой код нужно писать и переписывать? И, самое главное, какое отношение имеет комментарий к ответу?

Если это воспонимать как критику, то свой код я тут вообще не писал.

Comment: Это критика текста: "...и только в крайнем случае писать свой, но только один раз и на все случаи жизни..."

Comment: А, понял =) Наверное, Вы правы. Я имел в виду, что если уж писать контейнеры, то сразу качественно,чтобы потом можно было использовать их в разных проектах. А рано или поздно придет понимание, что же там не так,и захочется переписать. Про это забыл :)

Comment: Насчет писать качественно я не спорю. Но автору вопроса, по моему, сейчас нужны просто интенсивные тренировки.